# MySQL join count of related table

Tags: mysql

I would like to count the number of members in a project and join that to the results of querying for all projects.

I've tried messing around with sub queries and joins but haven't managed to achieve what I'm looking for yet.

Here's my tables:

**project**

```
project_id | name | description | start_date | end_date
```

**project_members**

```
user_id | project_id
```

For example, project 1 has 2 members and project 2 has 5 members.

Desired output of the query:

```
project_id | name | description | start_date | end_date | number_of_members
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | xxx  | xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx | 2
2          | xxx  | xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx | 5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried so far..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the columns you want from `project`. The `COUNT(project_members.user_id )` will give you the number of users in each project if you do the `LEFT JOIN` as shown.

```
SELECT
  project_id, name,
  description,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  COUNT( project_members.user_id ) AS number_of_members
FROM project
LEFT JOIN project_members ON
  ( project_members.project_id = project.project_id )
GROUP BY
  project.project_id
```

Comment: Hmm, your query seems to return only a single project record and the number_of_members column contains the total number of rows in the project_members table rather than the total users associated with that project.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clause. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! You seem to answer all my questions :P